# Jquery Mobile popup won't close

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I've been working with jquery mobile for a while and used various popups, today I made one that errors and won't close.

Here is the code for the popup:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="questPop">
test
</div>
```

and I am opening it with `$("#questPop").popup("open");`

closing with `$("#questPop").popup("close");`

Firebug gives me `TypeError: this.options.container is undefined`

and Chrome says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'one' of undefined`

Comment: The console output answered your question:

`Firebug gives me TypeError: this.options.container is undefined`

`and Chrome says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'one' of undefined`

Inside your function which you haven't posted here you are referencing an object yet it hasn't been defined, are you forgetting to pass it to your function?

Comment: It's some jquery mobile function buried in a min file

Comment: Can you post the full code of your open and close functions please.

Comment: Is it an external popup? If not, is the direct parent is page div?

Answer (score 0):

You should place this div in another div with class `ui-container`